# How to mock LocalDateTime.now() in an integration testing. I am using Spring Runner and not PowerMock

Tags: integration-testing, junit5, springrunner

I have to compare with the current time.
Any solution would be helpful, it must run in integration testing  `LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();`.

Comment: While abstracting such static coupling is the better approach to take, you can consider mocking the static call to return the desired values for the test.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that does not require any tools is plain dependency injection: Your code depends on something that tells it the current time, so why not pass in a clock?

```
public class Clock {

    public LocalDateTime now() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }

}
```

In your tests, you can mock that clock to return anything you want.

Comment: I can do  public LocalDateTime now() {
        return LocalDateTime.now();
    }
 in the same class But then I have to write separate test cases for the class and it will work only for that class . If I have to use the same in integration testing where I am testing one complete API , how it will work ?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in the same class, but if you do that, you end up where you started and can't (easily) mock the method call to `LocalDateTime.now()`. If it's a separate `Clock` that gets passed during construction it is easy to test your class by mocking `Clock`.